# What is tweening in css?

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

What is tweening exactly in css and where do we use it. When I searched online about it all I got to know is "The pose-to-pose option is to create a few keyframes throughout the sequence, and then fill in the gaps later. Filling in these gaps is known as in-betweening or tweening". Could someone explain me with an example code snippet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tweening is not a term that's used too often in CSS. As you discovered it has its roots in computer animation. Rather than telling the program exactly how to render each frame, the animator would tell the program what position the objects are in at two "keyframes" and the program would figure out how to transition the objects between those two points.

In CSS we usually use the term "animate", but the concepts are the same. MDN has a good introduction [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations). This simple example (from the article) demonstrates how to make a `<p>` element slide in from off the right edge of the browser window:

```
p {
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-name: slidein;
}

@keyframes slidein {
  from {
    margin-left: 100%;
    width: 300%; 
  }

  to {
    margin-left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```